# Connecting wifi usb adapter netgear a6100

Tags: networking

I have an Acer aspire xc-603 and have previously acquired a netgear a6100 wifi usb adapter. have any ideas of how to connect to my computer?

Answer (score 1):

Well plugging it into your usb slot would be a good start.....Joking aside linux dosen't take to kindly to usb wifi adapters unless they specifically say they work on the platform.

If you can and your confident enough to open up your laptop, buy a internal wifi card as they work more times then not on linux.

Just make sure you get the small square pcie card and not the full, big rectangular made for desktops card.